# How to mouse over button in multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can somebody tell me what is the error in my code? The button is not able to click and mouse over or mouse out also.

I try also

```
$(".userborder")find(".changepass").mouseover(function(){
    $(".changepass").css("background-color","#3CDCF0");
    $(".changepass").css("color", "#FFFFFF");
    $(".changepass").css("border-color", "#3CDCF0");
});
```

but didn't work...

HTML

```
<div class="userborder">

<div class="userheader">
    <label class="headertext">USER</label>
</div>

<div class="usermainbody">
    <img src="images/default_profile.png" class="usersimage" width="110px" height="110px">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="labelstyle">Employee Number</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="labelstyle">First Name</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="labelstyle">Middle Name</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label class="labelstyle">last Name</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="changepass" onClick="test()">Change password</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.usermainbody
{
border: 1px solid #CDC7C7;
position:relative;
z-index:-2;

}

.usersimage
{
position:relative;
margin-left:15px;
z-index:1;
}
.labelstyle
{
position:relative;
top:-115px;
left:145px;
font-size:12.5px;
z-index:1;
}

.changepass
{
position:relative;
font-size:12.5px;
background-color:#07A1B4;
color:#DCD1D1;
border-radius:5px;
border-color:#07A1B4;
height:25px;
width:130px;
z-index:2;
top:-507px;
left:730px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".userborder .changepass").mouseover(function(){
        $(".changepass").css("background-color","#3CDCF0");
        $(".changepass").css("color", "#FFFFFF");
        $(".changepass").css("border-color", "#3CDCF0");
    });
    $(".userborder .changepass").mouseout(function(){
        $(".changepass").css("background-color","#07A1B4");
        $(".changepass").css("color", "#DCD1D1");
        $(".changepass").css("border-color", "#07A1B4");
    });
});
```

Comment: why are you using z-index: -2 in .usermainbody class?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fcq6vvte/

Comment: i just try it, if the position is affecting the clicking and mouse over of the button.. i should delete it sir?.. sorry for a noob question

Comment: working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/146/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, but the culprit is here in this line :

```
.usermainbody{
  border: 1px solid #CDC7C7;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-2; // <-- here, so do you really need this?
}
```

And one more thing, you can group together css properties as object like properties like so :

```
$(".changepass").css({
    "background-color"  : "#3CDCF0",
    "color"             : "#FFFFFF",
    "border-color"      : "#3CDCF0"
});
```

And you can use `.hover()` function :

```
$(".changepass").hover(
  function () { //<--- hover in
    $(this).css({
        "background-color": "#3CDCF0",
        "color": "#FFFFFF",
        "border-color": "#3CDCF0"
    });

 }, 
 function () { //<--- hover out
   $(this).css({
       "background-color": "#07A1B4",
       "color": "#DCD1D1",
       "border-color": "#07A1B4"
   });
});
```

Working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/hrktwLto/)

Comment: i should delete the z-index:-2; ?

Comment: Seems so...remove that

Answer (score 1):

You added `z-index:-2` on parent Class that's why you can't even mouse over on the `button`

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcq6vvte/)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `z-index:-2` in `.usermainbody` class. And it'll work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Remove z-index from .usermainbody and change top,left of changepass.

Also you can use use CSS Pseudo-classes for your mouseover effect rather searching DOM again & again and applying css.

```
 .no-touch .changepass:hover{
  background-color : #3CDCF0;
  color : #FFFFFF;
  border-color :#3CDCF0;
  }
```